# Keeping image ratio for its height using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, math, aspect-ratio

Hey all i am trying to automatically get the height for an image. I can not seem to find any jQuery to do this?

What i am looking to do is something like it does in photoshop:

If the image was:

```
Width  = 778
Height = 346
```

And i want to change the *width* to **380** then *typing in 380 into the Width textbox in photoshop* changes **the height** to **169**:

[image]

```
width  = 380
height = 169
```

How can i mimic this in Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Njf5k/1/
```

HTML

```
<label>Original Width</label>
<input type="text" id="originalWidth" class="original" value="778" />
<br />
<label>Original Height</label>
<input type="text" id="originalHeight" class="original" value="346" />
<label>New Width</label>
<input type="text" id="newWidth" class="new" />
<br />
<label>New Height</label>
<input type="text" id="newHeight" class="new" />
```

jQuery

Its based on the fact that width/height remains a constant.

```
$('#newWidth').keyup(function () {
    $('#newHeight').val(Math.round(
    ($('#originalHeight').val() * $('#newWidth').val()) / $('#originalWidth').val()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why you need this?
if you just set one of attrbiute like height/width inline the html img element you see the image in ratio automaticly.